# Why tinycolor().brighten() is not working correctly?

Tags: javascript

I am using tinycolor2, I want to get  brighter colors from brandColor_Base
this is how my code looked like

```
import tinycolor from "tinycolor2"

const brandColor_Base="#338EF5";

export var  colors={
    
    brandColor_1:tinycolor(brandColor_Base).brighten(70).toString(),
    brandColor_2:tinycolor(brandColor_Base).brighten(55).toString(),
    brandColor_3:tinycolor(brandColor_Base).brighten(40).toString(),
    brandColor_4:tinycolor(brandColor_Base).brighten(25).toString(),
    brandColor_5:tinycolor(brandColor_Base).brighten(10).toString(),
    brandColor_6:tinycolor(brandColor_Base),
}
```

but because I won't to re-write each time tinycolor(brandColor_Base) I updated my code like below

```
import tinycolor from "tinycolor2"

const brandColor_Base=tinycolor("#338EF5");

export var  colors={
    
   brandColor_1:brandColor_Base.brighten(70).toString(),
   brandColor_2:brandColor_Base.brighten(55).toString(),
   brandColor_3:brandColor_Base.brighten(40).toString(),
   brandColor_4:brandColor_Base.brighten(25).toString(),
   brandColor_5:brandColor_Base.brighten(10).toString(),
   
}
```

this code is not working well, it is working like brandColor_5 is brighter than brandColor_4 and brandColor_4 is brighter than brandColor_3 etc and not brighter than brandColor_base (each time i remove one of previous line of code brandColor_5 is getting darker)
what should I do ?

Comment: It's maybe similar to -> 90% of 100 = 90,  80% of 100 = 80, but 90% of 100 = 90 and 80% of 90 = 72.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `brandColor_Base.brighten(70)` doesn't return a new tinycolor instance, but instead mutates the existing instance.

*In my opinion, this is bad API design of the `tinycolor` package.*

```
brandColor_Base.brighten(70)
brandColor_Base.brighten(70)
```

Basically brightens the base color then brightens the result of that color again.

You can fix the issue by changing `brandColor_Base` to be a function:

```
import tinycolor from "tinycolor2"

const brandColor_Base = () => tinycolor("#338EF5");

export var colors = {
   brandColor_1: brandColor_Base().brighten(70).toString(),
   brandColor_2: brandColor_Base().brighten(55).toString(),
   brandColor_3: brandColor_Base().brighten(40).toString(),
   brandColor_4: brandColor_Base().brighten(25).toString(),
   brandColor_5: brandColor_Base().brighten(10).toString(),
}
```

`brandColor_Base()` will return a fresh `tinycolor` instance on each invocation.

You could change `brandColor_Base()` to accept brightness as a parameter and use it like this:

```
import tinycolor from "tinycolor2"

const brandColor_Base = (brightness) => {
   return tinycolor("#338EF5").brighten(brightness)
}

export var colors = {
   brandColor_1: brandColor_Base(70).toString(),
   brandColor_2: brandColor_Base(55).toString(),
   brandColor_3: brandColor_Base(40).toString(),
   brandColor_4: brandColor_Base(25).toString(),
   brandColor_5: brandColor_Base(10).toString(),
}
```

Comment: If the only operation occurring is a brighten, that and the `toString` could also be moved into the `brandColor_Base` function as a parameter and just called as `brandColor_Base(70)` (But obviously that is much less flexible) Edit: I see you were already writing that type of approach when I posted the suggestion, haha.

Comment: @DBS Sounds like a job for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  :)

Comment: @Marco , @DBS, thank you it's working, here is how my code is looking like now            `import tinycolor from "tinycolor2"

const brandColor_Base="#338EF5"

const brighten = (color, brightness) => {
    return tinycolor(color).brighten(brightness).toString()
 }
const darken = (color, darkness) => {
    return tinycolor(color).darken(darkness).toString()
 }

export var  colors={
    
    brandColor_1:brighten(brandColor_Base,70),
    brandColor_6:brandColor_Base,
    brandColor_7:darken(brandColor_Base,10),
}`